# Why end line anchor doesn't work after lookahead?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm using C# and I have an issue with Regex.

I have next text : `123_456`. I need to capture only **123**, while making sure that **_456** exists and everything is on one string/line.

So, I've tried next pattern:  `^123(?=_456)$` and found that it doesn't work with end line anchor, everything is fine without it : `^123(?=_456)`

Comment: It's not limited to line anchors. It's kind of obvious that you can't put actual things to detect behind a definition meant to look _beyond the end_ of the thing you're detecting.

Comment: A lookahead is a zero-width assertion and doesn't consume characters (in other words, it's only a test). After the lookahead, you are always at the position after `123` and not after `_456`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put the anchor into the lookahead:

```
^123(?=_456$)
           ^
```

To make sure there are no `_` and any digits up to the end of string, use

```
^123(?=_\d+$)
```

When using `^123(?=_456)$` `123` is matched at the start of the string, then `(?=_456)` lookahead makes sure (or requires) that there is `_456` immediately to the right of the current location, and then wants to match the end of the string. However, the two conditions are mutually exclusive: you can have both end of string and `_456` right after `123`.

Comment: Is there a way to make (?=_456) optional, to capture 123 from strings :"123", "123_456"  ?

Comment: @Degot The point of a positive lookahead is to *require* something to appear after the current location. If you want to make some substring match 1 or 0 times, you should use a `(?:...)?` / `(...)?` optional group. So, to match `123_456` or `123` you should use `^123(?:_456)?`, and to only match these 2 exact strings, you may use `@"^123(?:_456)?\z"`.

Comment: I use lookahead, because it doesn't capture.  My original patterns are very complex => I can't work with '(?:...)', because it'll be impossible to extract captured Value from ~20-30 groups

Comment: @Degot `abc` does not capture either. You may capture inside a lookahead using a capturing group. What is your real test case? You might have oversimplified the case.